# mod_rewrite in <Location /> in apache conf causing rewrite in .htaccess file not to work?

Tags: apache, zend-framework, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I am using zend framework, which has a nifty example .htaccess used for redirecting non-existing locations to index.php to be processed by the framework:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -s [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -l [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -d
RewriteRule ^.*$ - [NC,L]
RewriteRule ^.*$ /site/index.php [NC,L]
```

And here is the apache config for /site

```
Alias /site "/path/to/zf/project/public"
<Directory "/path/to/zf/project/public">
    Options Indexes MultiViews FollowSymLinks
    AllowOverride All
    Order allow,deny
    Allow from all
</Directory>
```

While we are upgrading the site, I want to redirect all traffic to a specific file (offline.html, for example) except for a certain IP (127.0.0.1, for example), so I am trying to use this rule in the apache config:

```
<Location />
    Options Indexes MultiViews FollowSymLinks
    AllowOverride All
    Order allow,deny
    Allow from all

    RewriteEngine On
    RewriteBase /
    RewriteCond %{REMOTE_HOST} !^127\.0\.0\.1
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !/offline\.html$
    RewriteRule .* /offline.html [R=302,L]
</Location>
```

This seems to work, but for some reason it makes my .htaccess file seem not to work. I can access /site just fine, but I can't go any deeper to, for example, /site/controller/action.

Thanks!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The [Apache 2.2](//httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/mod_rewrite.html#rewriterule) and [Apache 2.4 documentation of mod_rewrite](//httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/mod/mod_rewrite.html#rewriterule) clearly state that rewrite rules in `<Location>` directives should be avoided. This caution was not included in the [Apache 2.0 documentation](//httpd.apache.org/docs/2.0/mod/mod_rewrite.html#rewriterule).

> Although rewrite rules are syntactically permitted in `<Location>` and `<Files>` sections (including their regular expression counterparts), this should never be necessary and is unsupported. A likely feature to break in these contexts is relative substitutions.

So strange things can happen. You could **remove the `<Location>` section (and `RewriteBase` directive)** and use these new rewrite rules directly in the `<VirtualHost>` definition, without any `<Directory>` or `<Location>` section. It's even faster.

The only problem with global level rewrite rules is that you do not have the `REQUEST_FILENAME` already computed (you could hack that a little but here you do not even need `REQUEST_FILENAME`).

You also have one error in your `RewriteRule`, you use a Redirect so the **rewrite Rule should use a absolute url**:

```
RewriteRule .* http://www.example.com/offline.html [R=302,L]
```

About the maintenance page, a classic way of handling it is with these two lines:

```
ErrorDocument 503 /htdocs/err/503.html
RedirectMatch 503 ^/(?!err/)
```

Where you do not filter on local IP, but the interesting part is that the code used for maintenance is 503 (temporary unavailable) which is more correct (in fact a redirect 307 is even more correct but old browser could have problems with it). To do the same with a local IP restriction and a `RewriteRule` it would be:

```
ErrorDocument 503 /offline.html
RewriteCond %{REMOTE_HOST} !^127\.0\.0\.1
RewriteCond %{ENV:REDIRECT_STATUS} !=503
RewriteRule ^ - [L,R=503]
```

Answer (score 0):

To have these rules in the htaccess file, you'll have to add/remove them by hand when you want to use "offline mode".

A better way to do this through the application is to create a controller plugin.
If the `APPLICATION_ENV = 'offline'`, the plugin would do `_forward('offline', 'error', 'default');`

Alternatively, you could write the logic in a subclass of Zend_Controller_Action which you use as the base class for your controllers.

Comment: I considered doing it through the zend application, but it is a little more complicated than that. I need to redirect all server traffic to offline.html, and not just traffic to the zend framework site (/site).

Answer (score 0):

Another option is to "stop" the execution:

```
    <Location /server-status>
        SetHandler server-status
        Require local
        #Require ip 192.0.2.0/24
        RewriteRule ^ - [L] # add this line
    </Location>
```

with sed:

```bash
sed -i '/Require ip/a RewriteRule ^ - [L]' /etc/apache2/mods-available/status.conf
```